# MySQL/PHP charset UTF_8 confusion

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I understand there are a lot of questions out there about this and believe I've tried to make heads or tails of it but I seem to struggle to connect the dots still.

So I get a xml data feed UTF_8 and store it in a MySQL table (DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci).  I have a varchar(255) that I want to be able to search correctly.  For the most part it works as expected but I have data that has international characters within them such as,

1. El CorazÃ³n
2. El Corazón

String 1 displays correctly in a browser but string 2 does not.  String 1 looks like "El Corazón" and string 2 looks like "El Coraz�n".  However, if I try to select 'El Corazón' or 'El Corazon' I only get string 2.

What I want to do is:
1. Process and scrub data feed to keep all legitimate characters and to discard any broken characters, newlines, carriage feeds, tabs, etc.

I have preg_replace in my php script but it removes Ã³ which I assume is a legitimate character.  More or less all international characters are removed and I don't want that to happen, I just want clean data.

1. I want to be able to search the table using 'El Corazón' or 'El Corazon' and retrieving a row that is equal to 'El Corazón' or 'El Corazon'.
2. Obviously, I want all output to the browser to be displayed correctly.

I've been beating my head on how to do the following,

How can I accurately scrub the data as not to lose international characters?

Do I try to convert Ã³ to ó so the search functionality works and convert in php to display properly?

Should I create two columns one for search and one for display?

Another thing, I want to do some more simple string formatting further down stream such as replace 'and' with '&' and other switching full words for abbreviations.

As I said, I've searched and I've tried iconv, mb_convert_encoding, etc. without get the desired results.

Any help connecting the dots would be appreciated.

Comment: hum... I'm not sure to understand all, but did you encode your connection to the database ? and which echoing page charset is using ?

Comment: No, I didn't realize that it was required.  Would this resolve my issue as "Your Common Sense" mentions?  That might be my other problem is that I'm not using a header on my echo statement which I can see now was a bad choice.  Anyways, how can I make El CorazÃ³n behave like El Corazón on a select statment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules are simple

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

(or similar function depends on your mysql API) after connect
and

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8')
```

before any output on your pages

Comment: Is it best practice and normal to always use mysql_set_charset after connection?  If so I haven't been doing that and that may be where my problem lies.  I thought if the table itself was set to utf-8 then that was all that was needed.  So my question would be that, if I set mysql_set_charset('utf8') then El CorazÃ³n will be inserted as El Corazón so that searching would work as I would like?